# IE 8,9,10 do not support .replaceWith() method during window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins

I am trying to parse DOM element from parent.submitData() method 
using .replaceWith() method using following snippet.

It's working in Firefox and Chrome. But I don't know why it's not working in IE 8,9,10.

During execution, IE 8,9,10 throws an error "No such interface supported."

jQuery version: 1.10.1

```
Parent.html

 <html>
        <head>

            <SCRIPT language=JavaScript src="/POCes/scripts/jquery-1.10.1.min.js">
            </SCRIPT>
            <SCRIPT language=JavaScript src="/POCes/scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js">
            </SCRIPT>
            <SCRIPT language=JavaScript src="/POCes/scripts/jquery-ui.js">
            </SCRIPT>
            <SCRIPT language=JavaScript src="/POCes/scripts/datePicker.js">
            </SCRIPT>
            <SCRIPT language=JavaScript src="/POCes/scripts/jquery.scrollableFixedHeaderTable.js">
            </SCRIPT>
            <SCRIPT language=JavaScript src="/POCes/scripts/jquery.blockUI.js">
            </SCRIPT>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/POCes/scripts/serialize.js">
            </script>

            <script>
                 var myWindow = '';

                function myFunction() {

                   myWindow = window.open("/POCes/view/child.html", "", "width=500, height=500");
                }

                function submitData(chdwndObj,fileContent) {
                    chdwndObj.close();
                    $('#theFile').replaceWith(fileContent);
                }   

            </script>
        </head>

        <body>

            <p>Parent browser window</p>

            <div id ="theFile" > <div/>

            <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

        </body>
    </html>
----------------------------------------------------------------
Child.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var parentwindow = window.opener;

            function submitData() {

                if (document.forms[0].elements['theFile'].value == null ||
                    document.forms[0].elements['theFile'].value == "") {
                    alert("Please Select File");
                    return false;
                }

                    var fileContent = document.forms[0].elements['theFile'];
                     parentwindow.submitData(window,fileContent);
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            <p>Child browser window</p>

            <input type = "file" id = "theFile" name = "theFile"/>
            <input type ="button" onclick = "submitData()" value = "Save Me"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

For more details please go to screenshots.

Please help to resolve this problem. Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: read up on IE window.opener and security zone restrictions. Could try using posteMessage API

Comment: can you give any example related that. i m new to posteMessage API

Comment: read about it in MDN docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: in this scenario its possible to achieve using posteMessage API. i dont no can you guide me to do this?

Comment: I am not familiar with the security zones issue and just found it when reading this question and poking around in google. I have never run into this problem myself. I gave you the postMessage idea as a backup...you may be able to do what you are doing if you dig into it some more. PostMessage is quite simple though and there is lots of documention and examples around

Comment: thanks for your comments. i will try to fix it soon.

Comment: Copying a file input, is it really keeping the value in the other browsers?